# Why would you use Char as opposed to String?

Tags: java, string, char

My question is related to Java but is quite general. When making such things as calculators I see people store the operator as a char as opposed to a string? Surely a string is easier to work with?

In said scenario are there any advantages of using char over string?

Comment: String uses a `char[]` instead of `String`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A char explicitly requires one character. It can't take two,  nor zero, and not even a null. This increases type safety where this requirement is appropriate.

Also, using char is slightly faster than using String,  in Java.

Comment: +1, `Requirement is appropriate`. So the answer is it depends.

Answer (score 5):

Also, char class has special method to check if the char is a digit and so on. Char takes less memory than a string because char is a value type and not a reference type. The char value will seat on the stack instead of the heap. Meaning faster reading and writing - better performence.

Comment: Good point about those methods. A single-character String can also emulate them with matches() and an appropriate [Unicode character class (or other regular expression).](www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html)